# Picking the pack in Canasta

Tags: canasta

When picking the pack on an initial opening meld.

- Can I use the two cards that I’m picking the pack with as part of my points requirements?

or

- Do I need the points requirements WITHOUT the two cards used to pick the pack (the two that match the card in the discard pile)?

Comment: This is the first time I heard you can use the card from the discard pile as part of the meld requirements!

Comment: It's one of the reasons that strategically, it's usually wiser to discard a 4-7 rather than an 8-A against an opponent that has not yet melded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the matching cards, as well as the top card of the discard pile, to make your initial meld's minimum points. The only thing you cannot count is other cards in the discard pile below the top card.

> The count of a meld is the total point value of the cards in it. To meet the minimum, a player may make two or more different melds. If a player takes the discard pile, the top card but no other may count toward the requirement.

https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cards in your hand to claim the pack, they must be a part of your hand prior to your turn beginning.  Any cards in your hand prior to your turn can be used as the point requirements, and this applies in all situations.

Comment: Can you better explain this answer? Currently, it doesn't clearly explain whether the cards used to meld the top of the discard pile count towards the point requirement.

Comment: Hm, I thought my answer directly applies to the question "can I use the two cards that I’m picking the pack with as part of my points requirements?", since those cards must be part of your hand (thus, any cards in your hand can apply to the points requirements, which is 100% factual and answers the question).  Do you not read it that way?

Comment: Appreciate your comment!

Comment: No, I did not read it that way, and your comment is actually longer than your answer. Now that you've explained your answer in the comment, you should [edit] your answer with that reasoning.

Comment: I see, perfect!